# sql merge question - updating not matched by source

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-merge

I have a stored procedure that mergers Local temp table and existing table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SyncProductVariantsFromServices]

    @Items  ProductVariantsTable readonly

AS
BEGIN



CREATE TABLE #ProductVariantsTemp
(
   ItemCode nvarchar(10) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
   VariantCode nvarchar(10) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
   VariantDescriptionBG nvarchar(100) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
   VariantDescriptionEN nvarchar(100) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)

insert into #ProductVariantsTemp 
select ItemCode, VariantCode, VariantDescriptionBG, VariantDescriptionEN 
 from @Items 


    MERGE ProductVariants AS TARGET
    USING #ProductVariantsTemp AS SOURCE 
    ON (TARGET.ItemCode = SOURCE.ItemCode AND TARGET.VariantCode= SOURCE.VariantCode) 


        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  

        INSERT (ItemCode, VariantCode,  VariantDescriptionBG, VariantDescriptionEN) 
        VALUES (SOURCE.ItemCode, SOURCE.VariantCode, SOURCE.VariantDescriptionBG, SOURCE.VariantDescriptionEN)


    OUTPUT INSERTED.ItemCode, INSERTED.VariantCode,  GETDATE() INTO SyncLog;
```

The problem is - i know in the output clause i have access to inserted or deleted records in case of **Not merged by source**. But in case 'not merged by source' I want to update

```
Update  ProductVariants  Set Active = 0 
// when not matched by source
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you have that insert to a temp table instead of working directly with the table valued parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Necessarily use `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 'when you want to delete a record that is not in the target table. if you want to 'inactivate' a record this must necessarily be done when the clause 'MATCHED' adding exceptions.

If you want to keep history of the records evaluate using "Slowly Changing Dimensions", I leave you some examples that Kimball uses for this treatment of historical data.

[Slowly Changing Dimensions - Part 1](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/08/slowly-changing-dimensions/)

[Slowly Changing Dimensions - Part 2](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/09/slowly-changing-dimensions-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` clause of the `MERGE` with an `UPDATE` statement.

```
MERGE 
    ProductVariants AS TARGET
USING 
    #ProductVariantsTemp AS SOURCE ON (TARGET.ItemCode = SOURCE.ItemCode AND TARGET.VariantCode= SOURCE.VariantCode) 
WHEN 
    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
    INSERT (ItemCode, VariantCode,  VariantDescriptionBG, VariantDescriptionEN) 
    VALUES (SOURCE.ItemCode, SOURCE.VariantCode, SOURCE.VariantDescriptionBG, SOURCE.VariantDescriptionEN)
WHEN
    NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    UPDATE SET Active = 0
OUTPUT 
    INSERTED.ItemCode, INSERTED.VariantCode,  GETDATE() INTO SyncLog;
```

Since the `OUTPUT` clause for the `INSERTED` table might return either inserted or updated records now, you can add the special column `$action` that will tell you the original operation as `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. Will have to change the `SyncLog` table to recieve this value though.

```
OUTPUT 
    INSERTED.ItemCode, INSERTED.VariantCode,  GETDATE(), $action
    INTO SyncLog;
```